# Enable f12 shortcut for firebug

Tags: macos, firefox

I was wondering, how to enable the F12 shortcut key on OS X for Firebug? I don't really use Dashboard, so I'm more than happy to disable it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable or change the shortcut for Dashboard in `System Preferences` -  `Mission Control` for Mac OS X 10.7+. In older versions of Mac OS X the appropriate preference pane should be called `Exposé`.

After you changed the shortcut, it should correctly activate Firebug instead when Firefox is active.

Comment: Worked like a charm, ty.

Comment: Nice. All I had to do was disable the default behavior for `f12` in Mission Control and the shortcut began to work beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>? It works on for me.